# The SQL LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

to search employee based on job post and experience we can simply do like this if the table contains field like job post and experience

```
$sql="select FirstName, title, experience from applied_employee where title like '$_POST[jobtitle]' and experience like '$_POST[experiance]'";
```

but what query to write when table applied_employee contains only id of the jobtitle and id of the employee. 
i m new to the sql query and programming.thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to join with jobs table to get the title

Comment: There are SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following query works for me

```
    SELECT e.FirstName, j.title   FROM applied_employee ae, employees e, jobs j
WHERE ae.employeeID = e.emp_id
AND j.jobid = ae.a_jobid
AND e.FirstName LIKE  '$_POST[FirstName]'
AND j.title   LIKE  '$_POST[title]';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table applied_employee does not contain the needed information, you will need to join that table with the other table(s) that contain the information. For example, suppose the other information is in a table called employee, then the the tables are joined by an employeeID field, the SQL statement might look something like

```
select e.FirstName, e.title, e.experience 
from applied_employee ae, employee e 
where ae.employeeID = e.employeeID
and e.title like '$_POST[jobtitle]' 
and e.experience like '$_POST[experiance]
```

Comment: actually applied_employee contains two id from two different table(employee and joblist ) 1st id is from employee table and 2nd id is from joblist table. so how to joined these three table .

Comment: i used following code to combine three table and got the result which i want :)     `SELECT e.FirstName, j.title   FROM applied_employee ae, employees e, jobs j
WHERE ae.employeeID = e.emp_id
AND j.jobid = ae.a_jobid
AND e.FirstName LIKE  '$_POST[FirstName]'
AND j.title   LIKE  '$_POST[title]';`